# Terminate a long running OSB request

Tags: osb

I'm using OSB 12c.I have an OSB proxy, which takes 15 minutes to complete each request on an average.

Lets say that I have five request now in running state.

1. Is there a way to see these running requests just like we can see the requests of bpel in EM console ?
2. Is there a way to terminate one of the requests without any impact on rest of the running requests ?
3. Is it possible to kill all request in case point-2  is not possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, not without changing things.

If you were open to changing the service to e.g. decompose the request into separate internal JMS messages, you should be able to use JMX to interrogate the MDBs and discover what they're up to. Then again, if you were to switch to JMS you could probably just look at the queue and get an idea about what it's doing just from the number and content of the messages created.

I'm not aware of the ability to cancel individual requests in OSB, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not terminate OSB threads directly.

You can configure your Weblogic to deal with stuck threads. (Thread that were running for a certain period of time)

You can configure a Dispatch Policy in your proxys using Work Manager to handle Stuck Threads and minimize impact on server.